# Data not saving to json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

My code is something like this:

```js
if (y[1] == "suggestion_channel") {
    saveJson.servers[guild.id].suggestChannel = message.mentions.channels.first().id;
    message.channel.send("Set suggest channel to: <#" + saveJson.servers[guild.id].suggestChannel + ">");
}

var save = JSON.stringify(saveJson);
fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', save);
```

Now it all works BUT the only part that doesnt work is the saving part.... The FULL code can be found [Here](https://github.com/AirplanegoBrr/Magna/blob/main/commands/config.js) Please be nice as I have been trying to fix this for HOURS thanks! :D

UPDATE:
Just use fs.writeFile not sync!

Answer (score -1):

The `fs.writeFileSync()` accepts a callback function, maybe use that and see if there is any error.

Try something like this

```js
fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', save,function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have u console logged that `save` to see if its actually holding the data that you want to save in the file?

Comment: Yes all old and new data is in the save variable

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync()` doesn't have a callback see NodeJS docs https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Comment: Also I fixed it by using fs.writeFile instend! thanks for trying to help tho :D

Comment: my bad, yeah @VictorPerez is right `fs.writeFileSync()` doesn't have a callback but `fs.writeFile` does.